# How to format a graphQL query to be called from graphiql client?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm new to GraphQL and playing around with a sample React-GraphQL-Apollo project. When I try the query:

```
{ 
  getStudentDetails(id: 12763454) {
        node(id:$id) {
            ... on Class_Student {
                id
                name
            }
        }
 }
```

from my GraphiQL tab, it throws me InvalidSyntax errors. I have the following in my code.  Not sure what I'm missing here. Any help is appreciated!

```
const querySchema = gql`
    query getStudentDetails($id: ID!) {
        node(id:$id) {
            ... on Class_Student {
                id
                name
            }
        }
    }
`;

const query = graphql(querySchema, {
    options: (props) => ({
        variables: {
            id: props.selectedStudentId
        },
        errorPolicy: "all"
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When making queries in code, you (generally) aren't able to hardcode the values you want to pass to a query as arguments. So, as your code is doing correctly, you give the query a name and declare some variables that will be passed into it:

```
query getStudentDetails($id: ID!)
```

You can do one of two things to pass your arguments in Graphiql:

## 1.

Use graphiql's "query variables" feature (located near the bottom left).

[image: example usage of graphiql query variables]

## 2.

Hardcode your variables *directly* where the schema expects them:

```
    query {
        node(id: 12763454) {
            ... on Class_Student {
                id
                name
            }
        }
    }
```